# how to set up an production environment with .net 3.5, iis6, sql server express 2005 on windows server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, asp.net, .net-3.5

I have a clean installation of windows server 2003. This will be my production environment.

I need to deploy an asp .net 3.5 project on this production environment.

But I don't know the installation sequence.

Also, I found this http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx but it does not have the versions that I need (.net 3.5 and sql express 2005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to do it in this order:

1. IIS6
2. .NET 3.5
3. SQL 2005 Express
4. Hotfixes and patches relative to all of the above